# Number of memory transactions in nested paging & shadowpaging

Tags: memory-management, virtual-machine, virtualization, kvm

For a simple instruction say

```
MOV memorylocationA, memorylocationB
```

Say I am moving value from one register to another.

If we consider a TLB miss and we are supposed to actually go through the page tables(I mean the worst case scenario),

The number of **memory accesses** in the case of **Nested page tables** would be 48. i.e, 1 memory access for accessing CR3, 1 for accessing the page tables, 20 accesses for translations through shadow pages, 1 for accessing the memorylocation specified and 1 for accessing the actual physical address so it would be 1+1+1+20+1 for each memory accesses. In this case we are accessing registers BX and AX so the total no. of translations would be 42+24 = **48**. 
Coz in NPT, **each translation in Guest Page tables goes through additional 4 translations in the VMM page tables.**

Now if we do the same using **Extended Page tables**, then the number of memory accesses would be 
1 for CR3, 1 for Page tables, 1 for memorylocation specified, 4 memory tranlations and then the same using the EPT so another (1+1+1+4=7). So, in this case, it would be a total of **14 memory accesses** (7 in the Guest OS and 7 more by the VMM as both page tables are used). and so a total of 28 coz we would be accessing two memory locations A and B.

This is my understanding. But aren't they supposed to be the same? I have studies that EPT is introduced by Intel and NPT by AMD and their performance is more or less the same.

So is it true that in the worst case scenario, the above instruction would take 48 memory accesses (if NPT is used) and 28 memory accesses (if EPT is used)

**Update1**: Changed the instruction to maintain clarity. Say I am moving the value of on register into another.
**Update2:** Say for each memory translation, we access the Page directory pointer, Page directory, Page table and the 4k Page.

Comment: Your sample instruction isn't valid. Also, I don't think accessing CR3 is a memory access - CR3 is a register in the CPU. Page table access may also take several memory references to get through the several layers of page tables... I don't know exact numbers, but I do know that worst-case accesses that miss in TLB and all cache levels are a bad thing...

Comment: @twalberg: Sorry about the confusion, I have updated the instruction. And regarding the CR3, yes its a register but we should access it to know where the page director pointer resides in the memory right. CR3 points to the memory location where the Page directory pointer resides and so I was calculating it as a memory access.

Comment: How do you get a TLB miss on a register-to-register move?

Comment: @AndrewMedico: I mean to say that I am accessing two memory locations, it was a sample instruction.